form serialize is not working after ajax request
I have a modal window that is populated using an AJAX request, and it successfully fills all the fields as expected. The issue is not with the AJAX request itself, as it correctly retrieves the data and populates the modal fields. However, when I try to serialize the form and save the data, it doesn't seem to be working. The form data is not being saved.
I've checked the code and ensured that the AJAX request is correctly formatted and that the modal is populated with the correct data. The data appears in the form fields, but when I attempt to serialize the form and submit it, nothing gets saved. I've also added console logs to check the serialized data, and it appears that the form data is not being captured correctly.
function getInfoForEditDriveOut(driveId) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'ajax/ajax_gate.php',
    data: {
      action: 'get_drive_info',
      drive_id: driveId,
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.success) {
        $('#drive_id').val(response.data[0].drive_id);
        $('#trucksid').val(response.data[0].truck_csdd);
        $('#start_truck_id').val(response.data[0].truck_id);
        $('#last_truck_km').val(response.data[0].truck_km);
        $('#trailersid').val(response.data[0].trailer_csdd);
        $('#start_trailer_id').val(response.data[0].trailer_id);
        $('#last_trailer_mh').val(response.data[0].trailer_mh);
        $('#trailer_stangas').val(response.data[0].trailer_stangas);
        $('#lock-key').prop('checked', response.data[0].lock_key_start == 'YES');
        $('#trailer_fuel_liters').val(response.data[0].trailer_fuel);
        $('#routes').val(response.data[0].route);
        $('#drive_note').val(response.data[0].notes);
        $('#driver1_ajax').val(response.data[0].driver1_name);
        $('#driver1').val(response.data[0].driver1_id);
        $('#driver2_ajax').val(response.data[0].driver2_name);
        $('#driver2').val(response.data[0].driver2_id);
        $('#start_date').val(response.data[0].start_date_dt);
      }
    }
  });
}

However, when I try to serialize the form and save the data, it doesn't seem to be working. The form data is not being saved. Here is the code I use for serializing and sending the form data:
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.edit_drive_out', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let $button = $(this);
    $button.blur();
    let $form = $button.closest('form');
    let formData = $form.serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    bootbox.confirm($lng.confirm_editing, function(result) {
      if (result === true) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/ajax_gates_out.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: $form.serialize(),
          success: function(response) {
            successOrErrorToastrMessage(response);

            if (response.success) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                location.reload();
              }, 2000);
            } else {
              return false; //Отменить закрытие диалогового окна
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});


so I dont understand why its filling but not saving the data here the code of my modal window if its necessary. Thanks to everyone in advance
<div class="modal fade" id="editDriveModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editDriveModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editDriveModalLabel">
          <?= $lng->lng("new_drive"); ?>
        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="editDriveForm">
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit_drive_out" />
          <input type="hidden" name="drive_id" id="drive_id" />

          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <legend style="text-align: center;">
                <?= $lng->lng("new_drive"); ?>
              </legend>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->lng("truck"); ?>: </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" class="ac_trucks" id="trucksid" />
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="start_truck_id" id="start_truck_id">
                    <select name="trucks" id="trucks" style="display: none;"></select>
                    <a onclick='$("#trucks").trigger("change");' style='display: none;' class="btn btn-info" id="driverlist">
                      <i class='icon-th-list'></i>
                      <?= $lng->drivers_list_this_car; ?>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>KM:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="last_truck_km" id="last_truck_km" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->trailer; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" class="ac_trailers" id="trailersid" /><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="start_trailer_id" id="start_trailer_id">
                    <select name="trailers" id="trailers" style="display: none;"></select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->motor_hours; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="last_trailer_mh" name="last_trailer_mh" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->crossbar; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="trailer_stangas" name="trailer_stangas" /> &nbsp;
                    <?= $lng->container_lock; ?>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="lock-key" id="lock-key" style="margin-left: 5px" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->fuel_liters; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="trailer_fuel_liters" name="trailer_fuel_liters" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?= $lng->route; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <select name="route" id="routes">
                      <option value="0"></option>
                      <?php
                        foreach ($routes as $route) { ?>

                        <option value="<?= $route['id'] ?>" <?=( $drive[ 'route']==$ route[ 'id'] ? 'selected' : '') ?>>
                          <?= $route['title_' . $userLanguage] ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php
                           } ?>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->notes; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <textarea type="text" name="drive_note" id="drive_note"></textarea>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <legend style="text-align: center;">
                <?= $lng->drivers; ?>
              </legend>
              <table style="width: 500px">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;">
                    <?= $lng->label_driver_1; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="driver1_ajax" class="edit" name="driver1_ajax" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="driver1" name="driver1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="start_driver_1" />
                    <a class="clear_d1 btn btn-danger" style="margin-bottom: 9px; margin-left: 5px">X</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;">
                    <?=$lng->label_driver_2; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="driver2_ajax" class="edit" name="driver2_ajax" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="driver2" name="driver2" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="start_driver_2" />
                    <a class="clear_d2 btn btn-danger" style="margin-bottom: 9px; margin-left: 5px">X</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <?php
            if (get_access('gates_drive_edit')) { 
          ?>
            <div id="additional_fields">
              <fieldset>
                <legend style="text-align: center;">
                  <?= $lng->additional_fields; ?>
                </legend>
                <table style="width: 500px">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding: 10px;">
                      <?= $lng->start_date; ?>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="start_date" class="start-date" id="start_date" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;"></td>
                    <td>
                      <button class="btn btn-warning delete_drive" id="delete_drive">
                        <i class="icon-trash"></i>&nbsp;<?= $lng->lng('delete'); ?>
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><?= $lng->lng("cancel"); ?></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success edit_drive_out" id="saveEditDrive"><?= $lng->lng('save'); ?></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

I have tried to save all data from form

Your form data isn't serialising because let $form = $button.closest('form'); doesn't match an object, therefore $form is empty.
It doesn't match anything because the button isn't inside the form. closest() - as per the documentation finds the nearest ancestor of the starting element which matches the selector. Because the button isn't inside the form, it doesn't have the form as an ancestor in the DOM hierarchy.
The obvious solution to this is simply to move the form so it includes the button:
<div class="modal fade" id="editDriveModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editDriveModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editDriveModalLabel">
          <?= $lng->lng("new_drive"); ?>
        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form id="editDriveForm">
      <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit_drive_out" />
          <input type="hidden" name="drive_id" id="drive_id" />

          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <legend style="text-align: center;">
                <?= $lng->lng("new_drive"); ?>
              </legend>
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->lng("truck"); ?>: </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" class="ac_trucks" id="trucksid" />
                    <br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="start_truck_id" id="start_truck_id">
                    <select name="trucks" id="trucks" style="display: none;"></select>
                    <a onclick='$("#trucks").trigger("change");' style='display: none;' class="btn btn-info" id="driverlist">
                      <i class='icon-th-list'></i>
                      <?= $lng->drivers_list_this_car; ?>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>KM:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" name="last_truck_km" id="last_truck_km" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->trailer; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" class="ac_trailers" id="trailersid" /><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="start_trailer_id" id="start_trailer_id">
                    <select name="trailers" id="trailers" style="display: none;"></select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->motor_hours; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="last_trailer_mh" name="last_trailer_mh" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->crossbar; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="trailer_stangas" name="trailer_stangas" /> &nbsp;
                    <?= $lng->container_lock; ?>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="lock-key" id="lock-key" style="margin-left: 5px" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->fuel_liters; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="trailer_fuel_liters" name="trailer_fuel_liters" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?= $lng->route; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <select name="route" id="routes">
                      <option value="0"></option>
                      <?php
                        foreach ($routes as $route) { ?>

                        <option value="<?= $route['id'] ?>" <?=( $drive[ 'route']==$ route[ 'id'] ? 'selected' : '') ?>>
                          <?= $route['title_' . $userLanguage] ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php
                           } ?>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <?=$lng->notes; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <textarea type="text" name="drive_note" id="drive_note"></textarea>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <legend style="text-align: center;">
                <?= $lng->drivers; ?>
              </legend>
              <table style="width: 500px">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;">
                    <?= $lng->label_driver_1; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="driver1_ajax" class="edit" name="driver1_ajax" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="driver1" name="driver1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="start_driver_1" />
                    <a class="clear_d1 btn btn-danger" style="margin-bottom: 9px; margin-left: 5px">X</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;">
                    <?=$lng->label_driver_2; ?>:</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" id="driver2_ajax" class="edit" name="driver2_ajax" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="driver2" name="driver2" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="start_driver_2" />
                    <a class="clear_d2 btn btn-danger" style="margin-bottom: 9px; margin-left: 5px">X</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <?php
            if (get_access('gates_drive_edit')) { 
          ?>
            <div id="additional_fields">
              <fieldset>
                <legend style="text-align: center;">
                  <?= $lng->additional_fields; ?>
                </legend>
                <table style="width: 500px">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding: 10px;">
                      <?= $lng->start_date; ?>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="start_date" class="start-date" id="start_date" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: right;"></td>
                    <td>
                      <button class="btn btn-warning delete_drive" id="delete_drive">
                        <i class="icon-trash"></i>&nbsp;<?= $lng->lng('delete'); ?>
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><?= $lng->lng("cancel"); ?></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success edit_drive_out" id="saveEditDrive"><?= $lng->lng('save'); ?></button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Another option would be to replace
let $form = $button.closest('form');

with
let $form = $("#editDriveForm");

so it selects the form directly by its ID, rather than relying on the relative structure of the HTML elements to locate it.
